# Simulate requests to url with different IPs

Tags: java, php, http

I have a php file on my wamp server that simply listens to new users that enters the page and prints their IPs.

I read a lot about IP spoofing and I'd like to test that.

Would it be possible to send multiple http requests from my computer and make the php "think" that different users are entering the page?

I don't care about the response from the php file.

Comment: You could set up multiple virtual machines and have each of them run your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you configure apache to pass a random REMOTE_ADDR parameter there is no easy way to do it from your computer alone. What you can try is using proxies to connect, this will offcourse require that you have a public IP or a server.

Edit: GordonM made agood point in the comment, you can use multiple VM's to simulate a set of servers with their own IP addresses.

Comment: Well you could do it with virtual machines (give each machine its own IP)

Comment: True, although depending on your computer you may only be able to spin up only a couple of them. If tests form a couple IP's are enough then that should be fine.